# non parametric test to detect price discrimination

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, nonparametric

Let us say that I have these columns for a product:

- Day
- Price
- Channel of sale (e.g. web or snail mail)
- Number of sales

Looking at the distribution, they can be bi modal as products can be on sale/promo or not.

Let us say there are only 2 channels. Is it possible to test for the null hypothesis that prices are on average (median?) not different for both segments? Can I use a Wilcoxon test (paired?) for this. Any input would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you would try to pair observations.

You could use Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney to compare Price across the two Channels. However, be aware that WMW (and other rank-based tests) typically do not test hypotheses about the mean or median.

It may be better to try to compose a more complex model that includes Day as a blocking variable.

Also, if Sale/Not_sale is the variable causing the bi-modal distribution, including this in your model may bring the residuals of the model to a normal-ish distribution.

I assume Number_of_sales would be considered a separate dependent variable, but it could also be included in the model as an independent variable if that makes sense.